# where is the join function?

Tags: string, list, haskell

I need the join function to add separators  between the members of a list. I found this function in Data.List.Utils and Data.String.Utils. Unfortunately, those modules doesn't seem to be part of the standard platform.
As it's a quite standard function, I'm pretty sure it should be somewhere in the standard platform , maybe with an other name.

Any idea ?

### Update

I have found the solution (but can't accept my answer, I have to wait for 2 days ???)

Comment: Note that the name `join` is often used with monads. In case of the List monad, `join` is the same as `concat`: `[[a]] -> [a]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it (thanks Hoogle), it's called `intercalate`.

Comment: wow. I kept on writing my own function that did the exact same thing. It is a good name but it needs to be better advertised.

Answer (score 7):

Data.List defines `intersperse` which has type `a -> [a] -> [a]` and `intercalate` which has type `[a] -> [[a]] -> [a]`

For example:
  `intersperse '_' "foo"` will give `"f_o_o"`
  `intercalate "baa" ["f", "o", "o"]` will give `"fbaaobaaobaa"`